# Graphical Ping utility with logging

Tags: windows, ping, network-monitoring

I need to continuously test the quality of the connection between hosts, and I would like to use ping for that, in order to see WHEN the problem occurs.

**It should provide LOG of the pinging, with timestamps of each ping.**

Any suggestions for such utility?

Yeah, sorry, Windows!  Preferably install and run.  Like, for dummy admins :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try EMCO Ping Monitor. It looks like it has it ALL :)

http://emcosoftware.com/ping-monitor/feature-list

Comment: The free version supports the most features of any tool I've tested so far. And it realy seems to be free as in free. Thx for this suggestion.

Comment: Hmm... limit to 5 hosts. Still, a nice looking tool

Answer (score 3):

[Smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) is pretty good for this. It'll show latency as well as packet loss.

**Edit:** Looks like Smokeping needs to be patched to run on Windows. See [here](http://dev.pulsed.net/wp/?p=3) and [here](http://dev.pulsed.net/wp/?p=31).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [PingPlotter Pro](http://www.pingplotter.com) for that.

Comment: Would have to second this recommendation.

Comment: Only works for 15 days for free, and after than it will only be able to record 10 mins :(

Answer (score -2):

"[Ping Monitor](http://www.myfavoritegadgets.info/monitors/PingMonitor/pingmonitor.html)" widget for Win7 does this OK.

Comment: -1 installer wants to hijack my homepage and search settings